# Offline Rails Dev Enviornment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I will be leaving on a 15 hour international flight next week and plan on writing a rails app that I've been thinking about for awhile. Since it's unlikely that their will be WiFi on my plane (I fly cheap), what is the best way to setup an offline rails development environment? I downloaded all the docs but I'm worried I'll need a gem that I won't be able to get and will be stuck. I'm still pretty new to RoR and would love some suggestions so that I don't have to give up somewhere over the pacific.

Thanks!

Comment: Download some tutorials, text and video tutorials. Maybe some good book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar experience. First thing I ran into was needing some documentation (rails guides, API docs). Sounds like you've already got that part. Next issue I ran into was external JavaScript dependencies (jQuery). I was using the Google CDN but that didn't work when I was offline. Make sure you have local copies of any files you usually get from a CDN. As far as gem dependencies, make sure you `bundle install` before you get on the plane. There's no way for me to know what gems you're going to need, but if all you need is built into rails, then doing bundle install will make sure you have all the gems you will need.

Answer (score 0):

Developing Rails offline is no problem, but as you noticed you will not have access to any gems. There is NOTHING you can do about this except to try downloading some of the more popular gems before you fly. Think about what you will have to do, or better yet, start writing it now, and figure out the gems you might need.

You downloaded the docs, which is good, but which docs did you download? If you haven't I strongly suggest downloading the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).